# How to make an edge copy the shape of other edge?

Tags: modifiers, edges

I have a plane that I use as *canvas* with *dynamic paint* and a sphere that I use a *brush* with *dynamic paint* too, so they both produce a wave:

[image]

**My question**: how can I make the edge (red) copy the edge (blue)?

Comment: I'm trying to clarify what you are looking for in an answer to this question. Are you hoping to find a solution that would mimic the cross section of the (blue) edge on the (red) edge throughout the animation lifetime? In other words, if there is no waves affecting the (blue) edge, then the (red) edge is strait, but when the wave(s) deform the (blue) edge, then the (red) edge shows the same deformations?

Comment: yes you're correct :)